# Using dynamically created SQL Server columns in where clause in a SP connected to SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to run a stored procedure by passing it `startDate` and `EndDate` parameters. The stored procedure creates `PeriodColumns` dynamically based on those parameters: 1 column per 3-months.

Examples (dd/mm/yyyy):

- startDate: 01/01/2014
- endDate: 01/12/2014
- Columns:

  ```
      id Period0Status Period1Status Period2Status Period3Status
       1  Active        Waiting        Passive       Closed
       2  Active        Passive        Active        Completed
  ```
- startDate: 01/01/2014
- endDate: 01/06/2014
- Columns:

  ```
      id Period0Status Period1Status
       7  Active        Completed
       8  Active        Waiting
  ```

When I try a select query like:

```
Select * 
from myTable t 
where t.Period2 = ...
```

it doesn't allow me because there is no Period2 column described in the definition. These columns are generated dynamically as told above. The definition of table:

```
Create Table myTable (id int)
```

On the other hand, a query like

```
Select * 
from myTable t 
where Period2 = ...
```

is somehow working fine even though the Period2 is underlined by red in the query. However, the problem starts when I connect this stored procedure to another application, Microsoft SSRS 2008. When I click on Refresh Fields in DataSet properties, it is giving an error saying:

> verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct

I can't define fixed periods on the table definition. Without defining them I am not able to use them in a `WHERE` clause legally - when SQL Server underlines it by red and says syntax error, even though the stored procedure is working when I use it on SSRS it is not working and giving mentioned error.

How could I solve this issue? Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: I think reporting-services has a fixed metadata requirement. Unless you set "default" names (field1, field2, field3) for the columns and always supply them in the dataset even if it's all NULL in your columns that are not mapped.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this in the past is to always have the stored procedure generate the same number of columns...whatever the maximum number of columns can be.

If you only need two columns, then return the first two columns with data and the rest can be all NULL.

Then use the visibility property in SSRS to hide the columns that are all NULL.